# Adding a new column in MS SQL Server Management Studio leads to database freezing

Tags: sql-server

I try to add a nullable bit column (without a default value) in a table with 39 records in it. On saving the studio freezes and isn't able to execute the desired change. The connected application cant't be executed either, I get a timeout there. I tried to add the column via user interface and also via a SQL command, with no success in both ways.

The table I'd like to change has several related tables. In operation there is no writing access on the table, but many reading accesses. After rebooting the server I was able to add the column. The update process lasted unusually long anyway. Updating the same table on the same server in another, identical database which is used only from a few users worked fine (within a few seconds). Adding the column in the local database also worked without problems.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to solve my problem and I can't reboot the server every time I'd like to modify my table.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: If you use T-SQL to make the change, rather than the designer (which can be awful), do you have the same problem?

Comment: Can you connect from a different instance of SSMS and run `sp_who2`?

Comment: I had the same problem using T-SQL.This morning I tried to add my column again (only a few users work with the application at that time and the last fully database backup was generated not long ago). It worked without problems. Now I observe the database behavior at different times to limit the possible reasons.